# C++ class declaration syntax in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, syntax

I am using Qt-6 for the first time and am relatively Amateur in C++. I saw this type of Class declaration and am not able to understand what it means.

```
class XYZ : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        XYZ
...
};
```

What is this called ?
Can someone explain what this is or point to relevant material / question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a class declaration in which your class `XYZ` inherits from a QT built-in class called `QWidget` which is the the base class of all user interface objects in QT (cf: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html ).

In brief, the macro `Q_OBJECT` allows you to use the system of `signals` and `slots` ( used for communication between objects in QT) among other thing (cf: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#Q_OBJECT)
The documentation states it like this :

> The Q_OBJECT macro must appear in the private section of a class definition that declares its own signals and slots or that uses other services provided by Qt's meta-object system.

Comment: I know inheritance. Didn't understand Q_OBJECT. Thanks